# Parsec not parsing newline character

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have the following piece of code:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Control.Applicative hiding ((<|>))
import Control.Monad

data Test = Test Integer Integer deriving Show

integer :: Parser Integer
integer = rd <$> many1 digit
    where rd = read :: String -> Integer

testParser :: Parser Test
testParser = do
  a <- integer
  char ','
  b <- integer
  eol
  return $ Test a b

eol :: Parser Char
eol = char '\n'

main = forever $ do putStrLn "Enter the value you need to parse: "
                    input <- getLine
                    parseTest testParser input
```

But when I actually try to parse my value in `ghci`, it doesn't work.

```
ghci > main
Enter the value you need to parse: 
34,343\n
parse error at (line 1, column 7):
unexpected "\\"
expecting digit or "\n"
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here ?

Comment: You won't have a newline character when getting input from `getLine`, might that be the problem?

Comment: `getLine` gives you string without line terminator, so you do not need `eol` parser.

Comment: Are you typing a newline character or a \ followed by a n? That's what the error message seems to indicate.

Comment: @DavidYoung I think a newline character is typing \ and `n`. Isn't it ?

Comment: The representation of the newline character is \n (in Haskell) but a newline character is generated when you press the enter key. When you typed the input in the program, did you type the two characters \n?

Comment: @DavidYoung I don't think that is the case. This parses properly: `parse eol "" "\n"` even though I actually type the characters.

Comment: @Sibi This might just be a misunderstanding, but I meant if you're reading input from stdin or something like that, and you actually type in the characters "\n". This is not read as a newline. If you have a string in some Haskell code that has "\n" on the other hand, that will be a newline character. You can see the difference in the output of `putStrLn '\n'` and `putStrLn '\\n'`. The `unexpected "\\"` error message makes me think that it read a \ character followed by an n character from stdin, which would not be a newline. sergeyz and bheklilr covered the other problem.

Comment: If you run `do { x <- getLine; let y = x ++ "\n" in return $ parse (many1 (char '\n')) "" y }` (`getLine` removes the newline at the end, so I put it back in with `++`) and just press enter when it's running will parse, but if you type `\n` it will not parse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're expecting a newline, but your text doesn't contain one.  Change `eol` to

```
import Control.Monad (void)

eol :: Parser ()
eol = void (char '\n') <|> eof
```

and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

"\n" is an escape code used in Haskell (and C, etc.) string and character literals to represent ASCII 0x0A, the character that is used to indicate end-of-line on UNIX and UNIX-like platforms.  You don't (normally) use the <\> or <n> keys on your keyboard to put this character in a file (e.g.) instead you use the <Enter> key.

On PC-DOS and DOS-like systems, ASCII 0x0D followed by ASCII 0x0A is used for end-of-line and "\r" is the escape code used for ASCII 0x0D.

getLine reads until it finds end-of-line and returns a string containing everything but the end-of-line character.  So, in your example, your parser will fail to match.  You might fix this by matching end-of-line optionally.